# Share member variables with member object for API backwards compatibility during refactor

Tags: c++, inheritance, unions, backwards-compatibility

## The Question

This question may seem strange.  I want to have a member variable sharing the same address space as one of the member variables of another member variable.  For example,

```cpp
struct Bar { int a; }
struct Foo {
  Bar bar;
  union {  // make a2 share the same address space as bar.a
    int a2;
    int bar.a;  // invalid syntax
  }
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.bar.a = 5;
  cout << foo.a2 << endl;  // 5
}
```

where I want `foo.a2` to share the same address space as `foo.bar.a`.  I'll also explain why I want to do this because there's probably a better approach that I haven't thought of.

## Why / Background / Motivation

I'm refactoring a library and need to maintain API backwards compatibility (not ABI, just the public-ly facing variables, functions, classes, etc names/syntaxes need to be backwards compatible).  There's a chunk of code/parameters that should really be moved into its own class, but I'm having real difficulty figuring out how to do so without breaking compatibility.  For example, consider this watered down snippet:

```cpp
struct NonlinearOptimizerParams {
  // these variables make sense as nonlinear optimization parameters
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
  // but these variables should be in a separate parameter struct
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};
```

and client code:

```cpp
int main() {
  NonlinearOptimizerParams params;
  int &lst1 = params.linearSolverTolerance;
  int *lst2 = &params.linearSolverTolerance;

  params.linearSolverTolerance = 2;
  cout << params.linearSolverTolerance << endl;  // 2
  lst1 = 3;
  cout << params.linearSolverTolerance << endl;  // 3
  *lst2 = 4;
  cout << params.linearSolverTolerance << endl;  // 4
}
```

I would like to split `NonlinearOptimizerParams` into 2 structs (the code should definitely be split this way based on the rest of the code base - I politely request that you trust me and refrain from objecting to my end goal):

```cpp
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
    int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams {
    int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
    LinearOptimizerParams loParams;
};
```

where `NonlinearOptimizerParams` holds a member variable of type `LinearOptimizerParams`.  But this would break backwards compatibility, ie `params.linearSolverTolerance` would need to change to `params.loParams.linearSolverTolerance` in client code.

So I want to keep deprecated variables in `NonlinearOptimizerParams` that "automatically synchronize" with the variables inside `NonlinearOptimizerParams.loParams`.  i.e. I want `params.linearSolverTolerance` to be an "alias" for `params.loParams.linearSolverTolerance`.  For example,

```cpp
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams {
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
  LinearOptimizerParams loParams;
  int linearSolverType = loParams.linearSolverType; // @deprecated
  int linearSolverOrdering = loParams.linearSolverOrdering; // @deprecated
  int linearSolverTolerance = loParams.linearSolverTolerance; // @deprecated
};
```

except where the equals-signs represent a "symlink" kind of thing (aka share the same address space).

Is that even possible?

## Preliminary attempts

#### Inheritance

One way I thought of was to let `NonlinearOptimizerParams` inherit from `LinearOptimizerParams` so that nonlinear would have access to all linear's member variables like so:

```cpp
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams : public LinearOptimizerParams {
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
};
```

But the problem is that *semantically* this doesn't really make a ton of sense because a NonlinearOptimizer is not a *type* of LinearOptimizer.  Similarly, a NonlinearOptimizerParams isn't a *type* of LinearOptimizerParams.  Rather, a NonlinearOptimizerParams *contains* a LinearOptimizerParams.  I worry that ignoring the semantics will cause maintainability issues down the road.

#### Union

Another, hacky suspected-undefined-behavior way I thought of is something like this:

```cpp
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams {
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
  union {
      LinearOptimizerParams loParams;
      int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
  };
};
```

But this seems like a nightmare to make sure the order of variables stays consistent across machines and over time - not really acceptable code.

#### References as member variables

I also tried something like this where LinearOptimizerParams uses references as member variables:

```cpp
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
  int &linearSolverType, &linearSolverOrdering, &linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams : LinearOptimizerParams {
  NonlinearOptimizerParams() {
    loParams.linearSolverType = linearSolverType;
    ...
  }
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
  LinearOptimizerParams loParams;
};
```

But now initializing `LinearOptimizerParams` becomes difficult and is incompatible with the rest of the API (I need a default constructor).

I know this is a bit of a strange question, but I hope someone has some ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only sensible way is with references. But you did it backwards, i.e. try it this way:

```
struct LinearOptimizerParams {
  int linearSolverType, linearSolverOrdering, linearSolverTolerance;
};

struct NonlinearOptimizerParams : LinearOptimizerParams {
  int maxIterations, errorTol, method;
  LinearOptimizerParams loParams;
  int& linearSolverType {loParams.linearSolverType};
  int& linearSolverOrdering {loParams.linearSolverOrdering};
  int& linearSolverTolerance {loParams.linearSolverTolerance};
};
```

You even can do macros to define these parameters, so that you can shorten declaration/initialization.

The only issue with this approach is that you need to either delete or define copy/move constructors. Because default/implicit implementations ignore member initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I did originally think to do this but I think there are some cases where this breaks the API (though at the moment I'm having a brain fart and can't think of them).
By copy/move constructors, you mean for the entire NonlinearOptimizerParams struct correct? (and not the individual member variables)

Comment: Oh, I remember now (sorry for the trash formatting):
`void func(int &a) { a++; }` then 
`int main() {
  NonlinearOptimizerParams params;
  params.linearSolverTolerance = 2;
  cout << params.linearSolverTolerance << endl;  // 2
  func(params.linearSolverTolerance);
  cout << params.linearSolverTolerance << endl;  // should be 2, but is actually 3
}
`

Comment: Sorry actually the above example isn't quite right - I must have just been silly and made a  typo before.  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, copy/move constructors for `NonlinearOptimizerParams` can't be implicit/default, since they will not properly initialize references.

Comment: So just so I'm clear: "real variables" and references are functionally equivalent to anyone outside the class?  Do I have to worry about rvalue/lvalue stuff?

Comment: Yes, usual reference (named lvalue reference) is alias for referenced variable and behave exactly same as original variable. I don't think you need to worry about rvalue here. You can read more about references here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference